# "One" can request a tax return transcript by completing the Form

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *one* mean in the following context:

> **One** can request a tax return transcript by completing the Form ... [link](https://inside.manhattan.edu/_uploads/financial-aid/irs_information_2.pdf)

Does it mean "anyone"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An author has a choice: the author can imagine that he or she is addressing the reader(s) individually or as a group, or to imagine that he or she is not addressing anyone, but merely stating things *impersonally*.

Authors can also choose to refer to themselves as "I" and "me" or "we" and "us", or to completely avoid all personal reference, and to leave themselves out of the picture, or to refer to their organization by its name.

When the writer chooses to say "you", the choice is the former, to adopt a *personal* style. When the writer chooses to say "one" (that is, "a person"), the choice is the latter, to adopt an impersonal style.

It is common practice to take the impersonal approach when writing generic instructions.

Comment: It may be worth commenting that you're probably more likely to see the passive voice (`A tax return transcription can be requested by completing the form...`) as using "one" might sound dated or overly posh.

Comment: It sounds posh only to those who don't read instructions. :)

Answer (score 1):

It means:

> A person of the same kind as the speaker

(definition 21 [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/one)).

They are being formal and impersonal, using "One" in place of "You", which is considered informal.

---

<sub>IMHO they should have just used "You" to avoid confusion:</sub>

> <sub>**You** can request a tax return transcript by completing the Form ...</sub>

<sub>Or they should have avoided referring to anyone altogether:</sub>

> <sub>A tax return transcript can be requested by completing the Form ...</sub>

---

<sub>Sometimes "one" can also be used in a similar way to refer to the speaker themselves (mostly in posh/formal BrE).</sub>

Comment: Thank you, one of my clients send me email that hase this statement "One can request the service and I receive the notification ...", Is it the same meaning?

Comment: @Shannak Yes, I think that the "One" there is also synonymous with "You".

Comment: +1 particularly for ferreting out that specific definition *(of the **same kind** as the speaker)*. It's obvious as soon as I read it, but I'd never been consciously aware of that subtle point before. By implication, there will be contexts where ***we*** is more "accurate, appropriate" than ***you*** as a less formal alternative to ***one***.